# How to change input(type="date") field placeholder to "YYYY/MM/DD"?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, styled-components, placeholder

I am wandering to find this solution half of day, but still couldn't find exact answer.
In my Next.js app, I am using MUI(V5) TextField(type="date"), but it's default placeholder is "mm/dd/yyyy".
How to change this into "YYYY/MM/DD"?

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
    div {
        height: 32px;
    }
`

const fieldProps = (name: keyof ScheduleFormState): OutlinedTextFieldProps => ({
    size: "small",
    fullWidth: true,
    onChange: (e: any) => updateFormState(name, e.target.value),
    value: formState[name] ?? "",
    variant: "outlined",
    error: !!(formFieldErrors?.[name] ?? false),
    helperText: (formFieldErrors[name] ?? ""),
})

<StyledFormGroup>
    <p>Schedule start date</p>
    <StyledTextField type="date" InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} {...fieldProps('startDate')} value={startDt && formatDate(startDt, DATE_FORMAT)} />
</StyledFormGroup>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this format.

The [MUI API docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/) indicate that the `<TextField>` component **type** prop:

> should be a valid HTML5 input type.

So, if you set **type** to *date*, you are using the HTML5 `<input type="date">` element. Mozilla's [HTML5 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value) for this element says:

> The date is formatted according to ISO8601, described in [Date strings format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#date_strings).

> **Note:** The displayed date format will differ from the actual `value` — the displayed date is formatted *based on the locale of the user's browser*, but the parsed `value` is always formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`.

This means, that even though you must use yyyy-mm-dd to set the *value* of the date, the displayed format could look completely different because the format is based on the user's browser.

If you must control the display format of the placeholder and date value, you could take a look at Material-UI's [date pickers](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/).